# Find the value $\alpha$ s.t. all solutions tend to 0 as $t\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My differential equation is of the form

$y''+(3-\alpha)y'-2(\alpha-1)y=0$

The problem asks that I find the values of $\alpha$ such that all solutions tend to zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

I found the characteristic equation and solved for the $r_1=\alpha-1$ and $r_2=-2$ giving the general solution $y=c_1e^{(\alpha-1)t}+c_2e^{-2t}$.

From here I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried taking the limit of $y$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$, and found $-1$, but I don't know how or if that helps me.

I would appreciate a general pointer in the right direction rather than a solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to consider the solutions $y(t)$ for which $c_1 \neq 0$. Since $e^{-2t} \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, it follows that $y(t) \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$ if and only if $e^{(\alpha - 1)t} \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$. This holds if and only if $\alpha - 1 < 0$, or $\alpha < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

In  your solution the second term has no $ \alpha,$ can be left as it is. The first term exponent should be <0  or, $  \alpha -1 <0 $

$$  \alpha < 1.$$